# Delete in Binary Search tree using python

Tags: python

Good day, I'm working on a home work that requires me to delete a target value, value, from a binary search tree, tnode; it also requires me to return a tuple. I adapted the code I found for Python 2. But its giving me an Attribute Error whenever I try to run it. I've been trying to figure out how to fix these to no avail. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong? Here's what I have.

```
def delete_prim(tnode, value):
    """
    Delete a value from the binary search tree.
    Preconditions:
        :param tnode: a TreeNode with the BST property
        :param value: a value
    Postconditions:
        If the value is in the tree, it is deleted.
        If the value is not there, there is no change to the tree.
    Return
        :return: tuple (flag, tree)
                 flag is True if deletion succeeded;
                 tree is the resulting without the value
                 flag is False if the value was not in the tree,
                 tree returned unchanged
    """
    def minimum_value(tnode):
        """This function searches for the minimum value in the tree."""
        cur = tnode
        while cur.left is not None:
            cur = cur.left
         return cur
    if tnode is None:
       return False, tnode
    if value < tnode.data: 
       tnode.left = delete_prim(tnode.left,value)
    elif value > tnode.data:  
       tnode.right = delete_prim(tnode.right,value)
    elif tnode.left is None:
       return tnode.right
    elif tnode.right is None:
       return tnode.left
    else:
       tnode.data = minimum_value(tnode.right)
       tnode.right = delete_prim(tnode.right, tnode.data)
       return False, tnode
```

Edit: I got the code working for some part, but I found a problem that it wont delete a node that has children.

Edit: Tree node implementation.

```
class TreeNode(object):
def __init__(self, data, left=None, right=None):
    """
    Create a new TreeNode for the given data.
    Pre-conditions:
        data:  Any data value to be stored in the KVTreeNode
        left:   Another KVTreeNode (or None, by default)
        right:  Another KVTreeNode (or None, by default)
    """
    self.data = data
    self.left = left
    self.right = right
```

Comment: The AttributeError I'm getting is that int doesn't have data or left or right attributes. tnode.x is how my professor coded his examples using a BST class. So I have no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: elif tnode.left is None: 
                return tnode.right
            elif tnode.right is None: 
                return tnode.left 
            else: 
                tnode.value = minimum_value(tnode.right)
                tnode.right.delete(ntode.right,tnode.value)

Comment: remove the whole else part  else:  
       if tnode.left is None:
       dummy = tnode
       root = None
       return True, dummy
    elif tnode.right is None:
       dummy = tnode.left
       root = None
       return True, dummy
    dummy = minimum_value(tnode.right)
    tnode.data = dummy.data
    tnode.right = delete_prim(tnode.right, dummy.key)
    return False, tnode  and add the above line

Comment: Can you explain this part else: tnode.value = minimum_value(tnode.right) tnode.right.delete(ntode.right,tnode.value)? You lost me on this part.

Comment: As you know the right side values are greater than left and the node ..so finding the minimum in the right subtree  makes it easier replacement ...since it is minimum but still greater than node and rest

Comment: Take a example here http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Binary_search_tree/Removal removing 12

Comment: Minimum to node found in the right subtree is 19 ..so using this ..node 5 is still less than 19 as well as left node 9  ..(maintains the BST and still the right child are greater than 19) .

Comment: Can you check the edited version to see if I did it right?

Comment: I put in tnode.data instead of tnode.value because the tree node implementation has data instead of value

Comment: can you post the tree node implementation?

Comment: @AaronJaredBagay  please do post the implementation or the online judge link